# Necessary condition for existence of periodic orbits

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $x'=f(x)$ be a nonlinear system in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Is it true that if none of the equilibriums of the linearized system are centers, then there cannot exist periodic orbits in the nonlinear system?

This always seemed "obvious" to me but I'm being asked to prove the non-existence of periodic orbits on a system without centers using Dulac's criterion.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like $$ \eqalign{ \dot{x} &= (1 - x^2 - y^2) x - y \cr
                                \dot{y} &= (1 - x^2 - y^2) y + x \cr}$$
Its equilibrium point is an unstable spiral, but $x = \cos(t)$, $y = \sin(t)$ is a periodic orbit.